# How to provide context while handing errors in C?

Tags: c, error-handling

Standard library functions set errno to provide context. We use it for disambiguation.

But what can I do with functions in my program? I want to write something like that:

```c
void some_func(struct error *e, ...);
```

Pointer to a local variable is passed to a function that may fail with error. If it fails, it sets error context to variable passed by pointer.

What matters is the ability to provide context when error occurs.

How can I do that?

The main goal is to write resilient software.

Below I briefly describe my research on finding something suitable.

I already tried to implement structure:

```
struct error {
        enum error_type type;
        char *msg;
};
```

There’s something I’m not sure about — registrating new enumeration items `error_type`. I’m not sure whether the following flow does not has any risks:

1. Register new error type in error.h
2. Return error with that type from a function

Are there any risks in this flow and what are they? Can they be eliminated?

Comment: Is C a hard requirement here? The reason I mention this is C++ has exceptions which are basically what you're looking for. C has no such system, so you need to roll your own. It's worth looking at successful C code bases to see what approaches they use, if any. Normally functions just return error codes, not complete structures like this, and you look up the code manually if necessary, or through a function if desired.

Comment: C is, unfortunately, a hard requirement. Return codes are not suitable for disambiguation. They make the same problems as magic numbers do. At least, we should use enum approach. I agree, it’s worth looking at successful C code bases, but I believe I can find answer much faster with stackoverflow community :)

Comment: There are a some libraries that mimic C++ exceptions using setjmp/longjmp. But I can't recommend one because I didn't use them.

Comment: Older C code bases, which I'm more familiar with, use an errno-style system where these numbers are reserved in a header file to avoid conflict. The approach differs wildly, mind you, as BSD and GNU, two very influential coding styles, have different philosophies here. The predominant convention is to return `0` on success, anything else on error, sometimes consistently positive, sometimes consistently negative. How you generate the lookup table is where the deal differences lie, as those can be automatically generated if necessary with scripting.